# iPad application UITableView delegate methods are not getting called

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ipad

I am using the same technique as i populate my UITableView in iphone while writing my iPad application.
Tab Bar Controller >UINavigationController>UITableViewController of type myCustomTable(load From NIB)

MyCustomTableViewController NIB and class file implements the delegate methods

```
@interface MyCustomTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

 NSMutableArray *PDFList;
 IBOutlet UITableView *PDFTable;

}
```

but my delegate methods are not getting called. What do i do?

Comment: fyi, I believe the newly preferred pattern is to specify IBOutlet in the @property declaration.  [eg @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *PDFTable]

Comment: I have already set this property

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the solution....

in the tableView delegate method
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

i was returning 0 and hence none of the delegate methods were being called.

Comment: jAmi - just a quick FYI... numberOfSectionsInTableView sets sections in the table, and then you have rows within each of those sections (that you set in another call for rows).. so if you had 0 sections, you have no data in the table and it won't anything.  You should always return at least 1 for this value.

So your problem had nothing to do with your delegate and datasource hookups.  They were correct.

Comment: This happened to me, I completely forgot about this detail. Please accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Did you set the delegate and datasource of the table in IB?  If you have, and everything is wired up, it should work.

FWIW - This is my biggest problem with nibs.  If you run into problems it's much harder to ask for help from people who aren't local.

Comment: Not trying to be rude, but *something* has to not be connected properly.  Assuming you've properly implemented the delegate/datasource methods, and have your property, the problem has to be in the wiring between IB and your code.  I have migrated code from iphone to ipad and I can vouch that nothing has changed in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have properly set your 'Class' in Identity Inspector (Tools -> Identity Inspector) in Interface Builder. Also set the appropriate 'Referencing Outlet' in Interface Builder.

Comment: this is done... anyother thing that i need to worry about....please...the deadline is approaching for this project and i cant get this basic thing to work